# Improvement or replacement to Toggle Comment functionality

Tags: delphi, ide, comments, delphi-xe8

As you probably know, the Delphi IDE's Toggle Comment functionality allows you to comment out a selected block of lines by placing the end-of-line comment symbol (`//`) at the beginning of each line.

So, for instance, if I had this piece of code:

```
procedure TForm1.ProcessLists;
var
  jItem: TJSONObject;
  i: Integer;
begin
  while not ADOAllData.Eof do
  begin
    jItem := TJSONObject.Create;
    jItem.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('list_id', ListID));
    for i := 0 to ADOAllData.Fields.Count - 1 do
    begin
      jItem.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create(ADOAllData.Fields[i].FieldName,
                                     ADOAllData.Fields[i].AsString));
    end;
    jArray.Add(jItem);
    ADOAllData.Next;
  end;
end;
```

and wanted to comment out the `for` loop, the Toggle Comment command would give me this result:

```
procedure TForm1.ProcessLists;
var
  jItem: TJSONObject;
  i: Integer;
begin
  while not ADOAllData.Eof do
  begin
    jItem := TJSONObject.Create;
    jItem.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('list_id', ListID));
//    for i := 0 to ADOAllData.Fields.Count - 1 do
//    begin
//      jItem.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create(ADOAllData.Fields[i].FieldName,
//                                     ADOAllData.Fields[i].AsString));
//    end;
    jArray.Add(jItem);
    ADOAllData.Next;
  end;
end;
```

However, I would prefer it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ProcessLists;
var
  jItem: TJSONObject;
  i: Integer;
begin
  while not ADOAllData.Eof do
  begin
    jItem := TJSONObject.Create;
    jItem.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('list_id', ListID));
    //for i := 0 to ADOAllData.Fields.Count - 1 do
    //begin
    //  jItem.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create(ADOAllData.Fields[i].FieldName,
    //                                 ADOAllData.Fields[i].AsString));
    //end;
    jArray.Add(jItem);
    ADOAllData.Next;
  end;
end;
```

i.e. when each line's comment symbol is placed at the position of the leftmost non-space character in the selected block. This way, the indentation of the current level of nesting would be respected if I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of the last commented line to add code after the commented section.

So, is there a way to improve the Toggle Comment functionality as described above or, perhaps, an alternative to it that would work in the IDE and meet the same requirements?

Please note that I'm aware of block-comment delimiters and realise that they make it very easy to comment out large sections of code. There are scenarios where I prefer them and there are others where I prefer end-of-line comments. This question is really about the latter.

Comment: I might be missing your point, but why don't you just surround the block with block-comment delimiters, { and } or (* and *)?

Comment: That is certainly an option, although not exactly an equivalent one. `//`-style comments can be nested however many times. For instance, I can comment out a couple of lines in the body of a loop now, then later comment out the entire loop, and still later a larger portion that includes the loop (for instance, the try/finally block where the loop resides). Also, I usually use `{`/`}` to document pieces of code and `(*`/`*)` to comment out big parts of code that include, or might include, brace comments.

Comment: Thanks, that'll give other readers are better idea of where you're coming from.

Comment: GExperts also has this functionality, but it doesn't format the code as you like it either. But it is available in source code so you could adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

- **method #1**

  Comment the block that you want using `//`.

  Select (*highlight*) that block and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> or just    <kbd>Tab</kbd> to adjust the position of that block
- **method #2**

  Select (*highlight*)  the block and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>

Comment: Regarding Method #1, in order to achieve the result I've described, I guess I'd have to first apply `Shift+Tab` to the block as many times as necessary to move it all the way to the left, then do `Ctrl+/`, then `Tab` it back to the original position. May be fine when it's just one level of indentation and when you only have to do that sporadically, but the reality is I'd want to use the method rather often and it's often more than one level of indentation that I'm dealing with, so taking so many steps would soon become annoying, I guess.

Comment: As for Method #2, I didn't know about it before, thanks for making me aware of it. It didn't really work for me at all, though. It ruined indentation of the selected block completely. When I tried it, the effect was that each next line of the selected block ended up with the indentation of the preceding line plus the original indentation. So, for instance, if the original block had 2-space indentation, after pressing `Shift+{` the first line remained at 2 spaces, but the second one was at 4, the third one at 6 and so one. Besides, I really want double slashes for my blocks, not curly braces.